# Deleting a Window profile manually kills the start button

Tags: windows, user-profiles

First: I cannot use GPO as that is outside the contract. DelProf2 does not properly recognize profile timestamps.

I wrote a script to delete old user profiles, and it worked fine until Windows 10 1909. Now if you delete a profile by script or by deleting it from the registry manually, the Windows Start button stops working for every existing or new user, except admins.

Deleting a profile through advanced system settings works, but some of these multiuser devices will get over 100 profiles and that is a slow process.

I can fix it by promoting the users to admin, signing on, then issuing the PowerShell command:

```
Get-appxpackage -all *shellexperience* -packagetype bundle |% {add-appxpackage -register -disabledevelopmentmode ($_.installlocation + “\appxmetadata\appxbundlemanifest.xml”)}
But I now have to do it for each and every user who signs on.
```

But I have to do it for each and every user who signs on.

I also tried:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

And

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}
With the same results.
```

Edits:

- This issue occurs with Windows 10 1909 and Windows 11 21H2; Windows 1809 and 1607 do not have this issue
- If I remove any profile from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList then it breaks the Start button for all current and new profiles except local and domain admin

This same issue has been reported elsewhere. The suggested fixes do not work for me.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/84540/windows-10-your-start-menu-isnt-working?page=1#answers
- https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/729498/critical-error-your-start-menu-isnt-working-after-user-profile-recreation/
- https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2311761-systemspropertiesadvanced-profile-deletion

Comment: You are correct, as I noted.

Comment: That's the issue, don't just delete the registry key like that—it breaks things now. You will want to run a PowerShell command locally or remotely if applicable and configured accordingly with proper permission `$usrName = Read-Host "Enter username of profile to delete";
$cmpName = Read-Host "Enter machine name to delete profile from";
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile -ComputerName $cmpName | ? { $_.LocalPath.split("\")[-1] -eq "$usrName" } | Remove-CimInstance -Verbose -Confirm:$false`

Comment: I will test that. I've been trying to use PowerShell but have had no luck reading the proper timestamp. But that is a different question.